Some memory alignment magic
I am now documenting a header for Variant Vector container. The file also includes some template classes, for example:
template <typename T>
struct TypeMemoryRequirement
{
  static constexpr size_t size_of = sizeof(T);
  static constexpr size_t aling_of = alignof(T);
  // extra space for align the pointer
  static constexpr size_t value = size_of + aling_of - 1;
  static constexpr size_t array_of(size_t count)
  {
    // only the first element gets aligned all follow up are tightly packed
    return 0 == count ? 0 : (value + ((count - 1) * size_of));
  }
  static void *align_pointer(void *ptr)
  {
    auto asInt = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(ptr);
    asInt = (asInt + aling_of - 1) & ~(aling_of - 1);
    return reinterpret_cast<void *>(asInt);
  }
  static const void *align_pointer(const void *ptr)
  {
    auto asInt = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(ptr);
    asInt = (asInt + aling_of - 1) & ~(aling_of - 1);
    return reinterpret_cast<const void *>(asInt);
  }
};

I have basic understanding of memory alignment, however I cannot understand what value static member is and why it is calculated as it is. I see that it is used in array_of method. I also cannot understand it.
I have scanned throught the rest of the header (2k lines of code) and failed to comprehend the usage of the code above.
If someone could please help me get into this block of code, I would be very grateful

It is bad code with bad naming. It is used exactly once to calculate the maximum number of bytes an array with count elements uses in array_of.

@PasserBy Sure, that is pretty clear. However, why does the author say that only the first element gets aligned? What does 'value' indicate?...

value doesn't need to exist, and it has a terrible name. You can try deriving array_of by hand to see why the code is written the way it is.

I think you need to chat with the original author.  This code does not appear to work correctly.  Does this code have unit tests?

The idea is that you want to compute the total amount of memory that you will require. That's what the array_of static member function does. The reasoning is hinted at in the comment.
Example
Imagine you have a type of size and alignment 4 and you have 10 of it. Then, if you wanted to place these in an unaligned buffer (i.e. a buffer with alignment 1) then the first value might, in the worst case, waste up to 3 byte (that's 4-1). This is because the buffer might start at address 401, which means the first, second and third address (401, 402, 403) are not usable. Hence the total size required for the worst case is (4-1) + 4*10 or 7+4+...+4.
General
The oddly named value constant merely says how many bytes the first entry consumes and the remaining entries are computed by simple multiplication: value + (count-1)*size_of = size_of + aling_of - 1 + (count-1)*size_of = align_of-1 + count*size_of.

Yeah, seems pretty clear now. But I must ask: does 'value' indicate MAXIMUM number of bytes possibly consumed by the first item in array?

@SigmaKlim Yes, it might over-estimate in my opinion. But we don't see the allocation happening. But normally an unaligned allocation will just give you something that is, well, not aligned, necessarily. So in the example, the first address might also have been, e.g., 402 or even 404. Then you would over-estimate up to 3 bytes.

Something else... Would you be so kind to provide a code example of when the situation which you described (extra bytes consumed)? Something like char buf[1000]; auto i = new(buf) int[5]; maybe?

@SigmaKlim Well the thing is, any buffer, however allocated can do this. Whether it is automatic, as you suggested with char buf[1000];, or dynamic as in new char[1000];.

well... I tried to simulate the situation with the code from the message above. I do not understand how I can witness extra bytes consumed. Will the buffer size change after I write aligned data to it, or maybe the pointer to its start will shift? I checked both variants and did not discover anything.

@SigmaKlim I just played around a bit and it seems that the compiler over-zealously always gives you 16-aligned (max-aligned) memory no matter how you allocate it (automatic or dynamic). Have a look at the addresses, they end in 0, which is 16-alignment. So in that case you always waste (alignment-1) bytes. One exception is if you have members to a struct, which apparently gcc does pack by default and therefore they have non-max-aligned addresses (third example in link).

Thank you for your examples. I got all that you said. However, I still not fully grasp this: If you put aligned data into non-aligned buffer (or a buffer with a different alignment), what happens (ignoring the fact of force 16-alignment)? Buffer pointer is the pointer to its first element, however they have different alignment, so.... will the buffer address be forcely aligned (and hence change its value)?

@SigmaKlim What happens is you have to skip a few bytes at the beginning until the first byte that satisfies the alignment requirement. See example in answer.
